# foreman - puppet run button click for the entire host group

Tags: puppet, foreman

In foreman, Is it possible to execute puppet run for the entire host group rather than performing it on each host.

Because I have 20 hosts mapped to a host group and applied a set of classes to this group.

Now its taking time for me to traverse all hosts in a group to perform puppet run on each one of them.

Is there a foreman plugin available which helps us to apply puppet run for the host group ?

There must be something available to make this work, without this feature, foreman host group is not complete and adds no meaning to it.
or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the *All hosts* page to get a list of the hosts you wish to run Puppet run, e.g. by searching for `hostgroup = Webservers`. You can also get this lists from the host groups page by clicking on either of the numbers in the *Hosts* columns.

In the top-left corner, tick the Select All box or choose individual hosts you want to use.

[image: Selecting hosts on All hosts]

Then in the top-right corner, choose *Run Puppet* from the *Select Action* dropdown menu.

[image: Choosing an action to apply to selected hosts]